# Sitecore disabled Media Library search after empty result

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore7.5

I am using Sitecore 7.2. When I search for item in Media Library and result is empty, search field is disabled. This happens just in 7.2 version, my other site is running on 7.5 and there is search field still enabled. Is this just some kind of wrong configuration or it was changed in Sitecore 7.5?

[image: Printscreen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wrote directly to Sitecore support. This is bug in 7.2 version and it's fixed in 7.5 version.